# Highcharts column + line combination chart with multiple series. Issue aligning line over the column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a multi-series column chart (3 in this case). I wanted to overlay a line over the columns across all series. So i created a 3 more Line series' with the same column series data. This works perfectly when there is only one column and line series. With more than one series, the line renders at the center of the category, instead of showing up on the corresponding column (Note: left shifting the line will work, but i dont know how).

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wm6dU/7/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: "Column Line Combo"
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                "Cat 1",
                "Cat 2",
                "Cat 3"],
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'USD'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Revenue",
            data: [
            49.9,
            71.5,
            106.4],
            type: "column"
        }, {
            name: "Revenue",
            data: [
            49.9,
            71.5,
            106.4],
            type: "line"
        }, {
            name: "Cost of goods sold",
            data: [
            83.6,
            78.8,
            98.5],
            type: "column"
        }, {
            name: "Cost of goods sold",
            data: [
            83.6,
            78.8,
            98.5],
            type: "line"
        }, {
            name: "Operating Expenses",
            data: [
            48.9,
            38.8,
            39.3],
            type: "column"
        }, {
            name: "Operating Expenses",
            data: [
            48.9,
            38.8,
            39.3],
            type: "line"
        }]
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about setting the x values for those lines? http://jsfiddle.net/qPqCW/

```
, {
        name: "Revenue",
        data: [
            {x:-0.2, y:49},
            {x:0.8, y:71.5},
            {x:1.8, y:106.4}],
        type: "line"
    }, 

, {
        name: "Operating Expenses",
        data: [
            {x:.2,y:48.9},
            {x:1.2, y:38.8},
            {x:2.2, y:39.3}],
        type: "line"
    }
```

To calculate the X values, I looked to the source code.  The following assumes you are using the default values of groupPadding .2, and pointPadding .1. I modified the getColumnMetrics function to get the general solution. Here's what I came up with:

```
var columnMetrics = [];
    for (j=0;j<index;j++) {

        var categoryWidth = 1,
            groupPadding = categoryWidth * .2,
            groupWidth = categoryWidth - 2 * groupPadding,
            pointOffsetWidth = groupWidth / index,
            pointPadding =  pointOffsetWidth * .1,
            pointWidth = pointOffsetWidth - 2 * pointPadding, 
            colIndex =  j,
            pointXOffset = pointPadding + (groupPadding + colIndex *
                pointOffsetWidth - (categoryWidth / 2));

        columnMetrics.push( { 
            width: pointWidth, 
            offset: pointXOffset,
            center: pointXOffset + (pointWidth /2.0)
        });
    }
    var series = [];
    for(i=0;i<index;i++) {
        series.push({
            name: "Column" + index,
            data: [
            49.9,
            71.5,
            106.4],
            type: "column"
        });
        series.push({
            name: "Line" + index,
            data: [
                {x:0 + columnMetrics[i].center, y:49},
                {x:1 + columnMetrics[i].center, y:71.5},
                {x:2 + columnMetrics[i].center, y:106.4}],
            type: "line"
        });
    }
```

This shows the results with 1 to 10 series: http://jsfiddle.net/b8gS5/

Comment: That works. But how are you determining the x values? I get a variable series length from server. So, if there are n series' with m categories (m values in each series), what would be the X values for line 1 to n?

Comment: The number of values in each series does not impact the calculation, just add the center to what would be the x value (0 through m-1)

Comment: Works. Thanks! Although turning legends on/off messes things up...but that is expected.

Comment: You could recalculate the x values in the hide event for the series.